# Incorrect syntax near '*'. (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5)

Tags: sql, sql-server, privileges, sql-grant

I have issue with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES` in SQL Server.

This is my query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON [FurqanDB].* 
TO '[Furqan]'@'[116.202.175.92]'
IDENTIFIED BY '[4aX%3bh9]'
```

but I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
> Incorrect syntax near '*'

Comment: That is MySQL SQL yet you have tagged SQL Server and that error is clearly SQL Server too. SQL Server uses T-SQL; the dialects are quite different.

Comment: @Larnu so what is the solution to that error how i resolve that issue

Comment: *"so what is the solution"* don't use MySQL dialect, use T-SQL; use the correct dialect for the RDBMS you are using. That statement will never work as it's the wrong dialect of SQL.

Comment: @Larnu could you plz write correct query here as i don't know how to handle dialect of SQL

Comment: If you're only familiar with MySQL, then I would suggest using that instead, or taking the time to learn the other dialect. You'll going to find using T-SQL difficult if you keep trying to use MySQL syntax on  it.

Comment: @Larnu could u plz write corrected query i even don't know what is dialect plz help me in this regard

Comment: @Larnu it gives me error here (Incorrect syntax near '*' ) so what is the issue with (*) .

Comment: @FurqanShaheen have you tried consulting the SQL Server documentation? Its very good...

Comment: @DaleK  what documentation i did not get yet would you plz correct the query

Comment: I didn't say anything about documentation, Furqan, that was @DaleK .

Comment: A quick google gives [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)